# "Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient" when using setTimeout in another function

Tags: typescript, overloading, ambient

I have a setTimeout callback but when i put this inside another function, I'm getting an error with `tsc`:

```
function delayedSnapshot() {

    setTimeout( function() {
        var filename = "/Users/dc/dump/heapdump.heapsnapshot";
        heapdump.writeSnapshot(function(err, filename) {
          console.log("dump written to", filename);
        });
        process.exit(1);

    }, 5000);

}

>> error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
```

If i remove the outer wrapping `delayedSnapshot` it will compile fine however.
I found something here on what ambient means but it doesn't seem relevant.

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries

can someone explain how I stop this error from happening but still keep my wrapper to control the callback firing or not?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error, and everything looks fine to me. Is that all of the code?

Answer (score 3):

Change the function name from `delayedSnapshot()` to something else.

There seems to be a `delayedSnapshot()` method defined/declared somewhere else, which is being overloaded here.

Comment: I can't check it now but it seems like a plausible answer.